# SDL C++ Frame Rate Counter?

Tags: c++, timer, sdl, counter, frame-rate

How do I make a frame rate counter in C++ & SDL, I know it's something to do with a timer, but how would I go about doing so?

Comment: Did you find nothing to get started by searching this site? ("[fps] [sdl]" in the search box without the quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

[SDL_GetTicks()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks) function returns number of miliseconds since the initialization of SDL. Subtracting two results of this function will give you amount of time between the calls. The rest is simple arithmetic.

There's an example at SDL wiki: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Average_FPS_Measurement

Hope this helps.